# SQLAlchemy relationships between three tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-2.7

I have three tables: Devices, Slots, Ports.

1. Devices will have several Slots
2. Slots will have several Ports, but belong to a single Device
3. Ports belong to a single Slot

In my experience, this shows up as:

1. Devices (one to many) Slots
2. Slots (one to many) Ports

I am trying to set up a relationship in my Devices class that will give me all associated Ports objects (regardless of slot).  I can't figure it out.  Association table looks close, but I am not able to discern from the examples around on how to do what I want.

```
class Devices(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'devices'
  __table_args__ = {
    'mysql_engine' : 'MyISAM',
    'mysql_charset': 'latin1'
  }

  did             = Column( INTEGER, primary_key=True )
  hostname        = Column( VARCHAR(255) )
  site            = Column( INTEGER, ForeignKey('site.sid'), default=0 )
  model           = Column( INTEGER )
  fqdn            = Column( VARCHAR(255) )

  slots   = relationship("Slots")
  changes = relationship("PortStateLog")
  ports   = relationship("Ports", primaryjoin="and_(Slots.device==Devices.did,Ports.slot==Slots.sid)")


class Slots(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'slots'
  __table_args__ = {
    'mysql_engine' : 'MyISAM',
    'mysql_charset': 'latin1'
  }

  sid         = Column( INTEGER, primary_key=True )
  device      = Column( INTEGER, ForeignKey('devices.did'), default=None )
  slot        = Column( VARCHAR(10) )
  module      = Column( INTEGER )
  slot_status = Column( INTEGER )
  card_status = Column( INTEGER )

  ports = relationship("Ports", primaryjoin="Ports.slot==Slots.sid")


class Ports(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'ports'
  __table_args__ = {
    'mysql_engine' : 'MyISAM',
    'mysql_charset': 'latin1'
  }

  pid         = Column( INTEGER, primary_key=True )
  slot        = Column( INTEGER, ForeignKey('slots.sid'), default=None )
  port        = Column( INTEGER )
  name        = Column( VARCHAR(200) )
  status      = Column( INTEGER )
  description = Column( VARCHAR(200) )
  op_status   = Column( VARCHAR(40) )
  substatus   = Column( INTEGER(4) )
  type        = Column( INTEGER )
  clean       = Column( TINYINT(4) )
  speed       = Column( INTEGER(10) )
  duplex      = Column( CHAR(1) )
  sfp         = Column( INTEGER )
```

The above is what I have so far.. I simply want the last line below to return all ports:

```
d = session.query(Devices).first()

d.ports
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with the ports relationship definition in the last line of your Devices class definition. I had to remove it to work with your schema locally. Also, you've not included any `__init__` functions, so I fudged those to create some example data.

I'm sure you know this already, but you can work with the device's port list easily if you're willing to iterate over the device's slots:

```
d1 = session.query(Devices).filter_by(hostname='host1').first()
for slot in d1.slots:
    for port in slot.ports:
        #do something with each Ports object
```

An easy way to skip that intermediate Slots level would be to add a little syntactic sugar to your Devices class:

```
def ports(self):
    my_ports = []
    for slot in self.slots:
        my_ports.extend(slot.ports)
    return(my_ports)
```

If you really want to compose the Ports on the same level of the Device as Slots, you will need to construct an [AssociationProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#composite-association-proxy) (not an [Association](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#association-object)) to map the collection of Ports. However, since you are not maintaining a many-to-many relationship, the AssociationProxy seems like overkill and will take some work to get it to return a list of Ports objects rather than a list of pids.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I haven't responded.  I will review this and update this comment/approve if it solves my issue.  I didn't even notice this til just now!